# Replace first FROM in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query engine on a web app, what needs to be accomplish is that a user can enter any `SELECT` statement into a textbox and then the results should be created into a new table.

This is my function I have created but it only support SQL Server 2012 and I want similar to this function but only it should support SQL Server 2005 and above:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CustomQueryTableCreation]
(
    @TableName varchar(max),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS 
  @TableBuilder TABLE
  (
     DS varchar(max)
  )
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @TableBuilder
  SELECT 'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + @TableName+'(';

  INSERT INTO @TableBuilder
  SELECT 
   CASE column_ordinal 
     WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ',' END 
     + name + ' ' + system_type_name + CASE is_nullable 
     WHEN 0 THEN ' not null' ELSE '' END
  FROM 
  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
  (
    @sql, NULL, 0
  ) AS f
  ORDER BY
  column_ordinal;

  INSERT INTO @TableBuilder
  SELECT ');';

  RETURN 
END
```

What I want to do now is that I want to search through my query and replace the FIRST `FROM` with `INTO NewTable FROM`.

The query can contain multiple joins.

Should I control this with SQL or C#?

Comment: You could try playing with the combination of `SET FMTONLY ON` + `SELECT * INTO newtable FROM OPENQUERY(..., 'user SELECT')` + `SET FMTONLY OFF` + (in a new batch) `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT ...` (user SELECT), but I'm not sure how well that would work with queries returning IDENTITY columns. In any event, you would probably need to account for output columns with identical names.

Comment: Just so you're aware - tables have no order - and there's no obvious column in your result table to perform an `ORDER BY` - so there's no guarantee that whatever is reading from your return value won't obtain `);` as the "first" row. If the results you're producing are meant to be consumed in a specific order, you ought to add a column to allow that to be done easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the 2005 Environment. If you save the Select query to a table, and use the following built in procedure to execute the query:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Here is the MS docs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

*Edit*

Keeping this in mind, can take the SQL dumps and Create OpenRowset Queries to take the SQL and dump them into a TempTable, and from the Temp Table to a permanent table if required.

I created the following SP's to assist with getting the info to a permanent table.
First the procedure to execute the specific SQL Statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spExecuteRowset]
(
    @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

--Execute SQL Statement
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query

END
```

Then the OpenRowset SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCustomquery]
(
    @ProQuery NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Tablename NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)
AS 
BEGIN

--Insert the info into a Specidied Table
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(max)
SET @Query = 'SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'','' EXEC [YOUR DATABASE].dbo.spExecuteRowset' +''''+@ProQuery+''''') SELECT * INTO '+ @Tablename +' FROM #MyTempTable'

--FOR DEBUG ONLY!!!!
PRINT @Query

EXEC [YourDatabase].dbo.spExecuteRowset @Query

END
```

This takes it from the #tempTable to A Physical Table.

**[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)** are some docs on OpenRowset.

Comment: How does this save the results into a table?

Answer (score 1):

You have no guarantee that the first `from` in a query will accept an `into`, because you can have a subselect in the `select` statement.  In addition, you could have a field name like `datefrom` that throws things off too.

But, assuming you have "simple" SQL statements, you can do it as:

```
select stuff(@query, charindex('from ', @query), 0, 'into '+@Table+' ')
from t;
```

EDIT:

The following is what you really want to do:

```
select *
into @Table
from (@query) q;
```

Using the subquery solves the problem.

Comment: See this is my problem the query can be anything from a simple select statement to a more advanced select statement with subselects and joins as well. That is why I want to catch the first FROM

Comment: @G-Man . . . That is what this expression does.  I'm just saying that it might not work in all cases.  This answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known problem. String concatenation is usually a bad/limited solution.
The more recommended solution is to let some other mechanism to return you the result set (openquery etc.), and then insert it to a table.

For example:

```
SELECT *
INTO YourTable
FROM OPENQUERY([LinkedServer],your query...)
```